# How can I implement Custom Camera using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using swift 3.0 and want to implement my custom camera with full view layout. For example when we take video from iPhone default camera the view is look same as I want.

Now I searched out various links and examples which are working fine on swift 2.3 but when I convert that code and try to implement in swift 3.0. It throws me lots of crashes and sometimes some methods are not supporting which was fine in swift 2.3.

Here is one my code snippet for explaining that was throwing me crash:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate   { 

  var sessionOutputSetting = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG])
}
```

When I run it crashed on `sessionOutputSetting` saying

> ExeBadAccess

Still I don't get any proper way to implement the whole logic.

**I don't want to use any kind of camera overlay.**